# Как в списке обнулить каждый второй элемент при помощи цикла for в Python

Tags: python

Дан следующий список:

```
    prices = [25.8, 45.2, 46.5, 60.4, 61.8, 88.3, 112.7]
```

Нужно написать два цикла for, один из которых обнулит каждый второй элемент списка (передать диапазон нужно с помощью функций range() и len() и использовать срезы). Второй цикл for должен просуммировать оставшиеся элементы, записав получившееся значение в переменную.
Мой код

```
    for price in range(len(prices[1::2])):
        prices[price] *= 0
    print(prices)
```

выдает список

```
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 60.4, 61.8, 88.3, 112.7]
```

вместо

```
    [25.8, 0.0, 46.5, 0.0, 61.8, 0.0, 112.7]
```

Буду благодарна всем, кто укажет на мою ошибку в первом цикле и поможет разобраться со вторым. Заранее всем большое спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://tio.run/##NYxBCoMwEEX3c4q/VBgGE42GQk8iLkRiG5BRUjc9fZoibh68z@cd3/O9a5vzkeISPnhitE48o3NiC3txjL6RrtD8d@@lZRhjZZiI1j0hIirSrK9QGcYWtLpaNcPWDwIuHeNU6g1RUT3vT84/

```
prices = [25.8, 45.2, 46.5, 60.4, 61.8, 88.3, 112.7]

for i in range(1, len(prices), 2):
  prices[i] = 0

print(prices)
```

```
[25.8, 0, 46.5, 0, 61.8, 0, 112.7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Используя range. Можно задать шаг третьим параметром. Пример:

```py
    list = [...]

    for i in range(0, len(list), 2):
       list[i] = 0
```

Соотвественно сделать это подобным образом (перепроверьте и отладьте код пожалуйста)

P.S Если Вы считаете сумму, лучше не обнулять элемент, а вырезать его. Например используя функцию `pop()`